# why is vim calling this script on startup?

Tags: vim, macvim

I'm trying to use a custom color scheme.

On startup, I can see that vim is loading my scheme, but after that it loads *another* scheme, overwriting mine.

Here's the output of `:scriptnames`:

```
  1: /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-72/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/vimrc
  2: ~/.vimrc
  3: ~/.vim/colors/torte2.vim
  4: /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-72/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/syntax/syntax.vim
  5: /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-72/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/syntax/synload.vim
  6: /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-72/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/colors/torte.vim
  7: /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-72/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/syntax/syncolor.vim
  ... and so on
```

As you can see, my colorscheme "torte2" is loaded in line 3, but then it's clobbered by "torte" in line 6.

Why is it doing that, and how can I make it stop?

Comment: Can you share your colorscheme and your vimrc? Is this [this one](https://github.com/ajford/dotfiles/blob/master/vim/vim.symlink/colors/torte2.vim)? If so you should change `let g:colors_name = "torte"` to `let g:colors_name = "torte2"`.

Comment: No, my torte2 is just a copy of the regular torte with some modifications I made.

Comment: Is it still called "torte" or did you change it to "torte2"? Also, where is your vimrc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you clone a colorscheme, you need to adapt the `g:colors_name` inside the script; its value must be identical with the changed name. That's because the following snippet of `syntax/synload.vim` will re-load the colorscheme:

```
" Set the default highlighting colors.  Use a color scheme if specified.
if exists("colors_name")
    exe "colors " . colors_name
else
```

You forgot to adapt the name, so Vim is re-loading `torte.vim` instead of your `torte2.vim`.

---

Alternatively, you can rename your cloned script to `torte.vim`; if it's earlier in the `'runtimepath'`, Vim will prefer that over the one that ships with Vim.

Comment: Ah, yep, that's exactly what I did.  I didn't notice `g:colors_name` inside the scheme that I copied, so it still said 'torte'.  As soon as I changed it to 'torte2', the problem resolved.  Thanks!